# VBA If statement with multiple actions when true

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried reading through potential solutions in other posts on this forum but I am not having any luck. This seems like it should be a simple action but I am making no progress.

I have the below code which I want to check through each row on a worksheet, if the value held in column D is greater than a set amount to clear contents held in cells further along the same row.

```
Sub ClearData()
 
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

'   Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
'   Loop through range and clear data in specified cells if condition met
    For i = 2 To myLastRow
        If Cells(i, "D").Value >= 365 Then
        Cells(i, "Z").ClearContents
        Cells(i, "AB").ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

The error message I keep getting is "run time error '13' - Type mismatch"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have error values in column D?

Comment: I did but I have since removed all of these all values are now showing "0" or greater

Comment: Apologies just double checked and missed an error value, now amended the formula in original sheet with an IFERROR statement and code now working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A stronger alternative would be to modify the code to validate cell contents before using it with operators; `If IsNumeric(..)` could give you an `Else` branch to handle such bad inputs.